# nuxtjs head meta tag dynamic modify on fetch()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, meta-tags, head, nuxtjs

I have this component in Nuxtjs, which renders content fetched using fetch method from API. API gives back data as nested object. When I pass this data to head() method for meta tags it works only one level deep, but not with nested data. Why is that?

In this code we assign recived data to const post in components data() `this.post = data.response.results[0];`. Then when using `this.post.webTitle` its fine, but when using `this.post.fields.thumbnail` an error occurs stating thumbnail is undefined.

```js
export default {
  async fetch() {
    const { data } = await this.$axios.get(
      `api_url`
    );
    this.post = data.response.results[0];
    this.loading = false;
  },
  data() {
    return {
      post: {},
    };
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.post.webTitle ? `${this.post.webTitle.slice(0, 10)}...` : "",
      meta: [
        {
          hid: "description",
          name: "description",
          content: this.post.webTitle,
        },
        { hid: "og-title", property: "og:title", content: this.post.webTitle },
        {
          hid: "og-image",
          property: "og:image",
          content: this.post.fields.thumbnail,
        },
        { hid: "og-image-width", property: "og:image:width", content: 500 },
        { hid: "og-image-height", property: "og:image:height", content: 300 },
        {
          hid: "og-image-type",
          property: "og:image:type",
          content: "image/jpeg",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
```

when separately assign

```js
this.post = data.response.results[0];
this.thumbnail = data.response.results[0].fields.thumbnail;

data() {
    return {
      post: {},
      thumbnail: "",
    };
  },
```

then its working ok, I I can use:

```js
this.thumbnail
```

I don't understand why it's not working in the first way? Why I have to separately assign "deeper" data to make it available to component?

Thank you for help in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely because `head` is run before `fetch` is able to return data. As `this.post` is defined as an object, it is legal to access `this.post.webTitle` as it would just be undefined. But `this.post.fields.thumbnail` is trying to access `thumbnail` of undefined, which is illegal.

If you change `data` to:

```
data() {
    return {
      post: {
          fields: {
              thumbnail: ""
          }
      },
    };
  },
```

I suspect it would work

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You were right. Adding thumbnail into post structure definition make it work.